# Как добавить треугольный уголок к всплывающей подсказке с помощью стилей?

Tags: html, css, css3

Всем привет. Хочу добавить всплывающую подсказку [image: вот такую]с помощью стилей. Все бы ничего, но меня интересует как добавить маленький уголок снизу. Пробовал с помощью [онлайн сервиса](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/), но не выходит..

```css
.compare.question:before {
  content: "\f059";
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.compare.question:after {
  content: "";
}
.compare.question:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  background-color: #e7e2e2;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  color: #696e6e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0 7px;
  border-color: #e7e2e2 transparent transparent transparent;
  left: -80%;
  top: -100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="compare question" data-title="Задать вопрос"></a>
```

Comment: Вот это поможет: http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/

Comment: @Sergey Snegirev и чем же поможет? вы хоть контекст вопроса посмотрели или сразу в ссылку тыкать?

Comment: Там русским языком описано как "добавить маленький уголок снизу".  Разумеется, не для тех, кто любит SO за то, что тут ему весь код напишут.

Comment: @Sergey Snegirev то, что ссылке -на русском языке ответ на вопрос как НАРИСОВАТЬ уголок, а не как ДОБАВИТЬ - разницу улавливаете? сам уголок я знаю как рисовать - для этого есть сервисы об одном из которых я упоминал. Мой случай нетривиальный, если вы это заметили и про какой весь код вы говорите? я разве о многом спрашиваю? - для знающих людей это пара строк кода в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
body {
    margin: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}
.question {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.question:before, .question:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.question:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute; bottom: 110%; left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #E7E2E2;
    color: #000;    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.question:after {
    content:" ";
    position: absolute; bottom: 110%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid #E7E2E2;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;    
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.question:hover:before, .question:hover:after {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="question" data-tooltip="Задать вопрос">
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
</a>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/uywmz3es/)

Пример 2(добавление треугольника)

```css
div {
    background: #E7E2E2;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -26px;
    margin-left: -16px;
    border: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #E7E2E2;
}
```

```html
<div>Задать вопрос</div>
```

Comment: уже лучше. но то что у меня ссылка, а не div это еще пол беды, настоящая жесть проявляется в том, что в самой ссылке текста нет, свойства :before занято иконкой, а :after переопределением и я пока не знаю как это можно обойти...

Comment: все супер, спасибо! Единственный момент у меня `<i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>` был оформлен как  `question:before {content: "\f059"; font-family: 'fontawesome';}` можно как-то сделать так, чтобы не изменять html структуру или в этом случае никак?